# Problem in Value Change Listener

Tags: jsf

HI,

I am having a problem in the Value Change Listener. Some times listener is not activated when we are changing the value. Because, it is retaining the old value. We want to know, how to over write the current selected value in the JSF life-cycle. Some where it is lost in the previous action we are doing the application. I just want to know how to over write the currently selected value.

Comment: Could you post some code to be more specific with this?

Comment: The ValueChangeListener will **not** be called if you have validation errors on this field. Maybe this is your case, no? Please post your code...

Comment: Please let me know how to set the selected value

Comment: Please show us the codez ;) It's really hard to see where it possible goes wrong or what you even exactly mean without those.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC explains a lot here: [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)

I suggest you add a `<f:ajax>` to your component, or completely remove the ValueChangeListener and replace with `<f:ajax listener="...">`.