# When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, listener, valuechangelistener

What's the difference between the following two pieces of code - with regards to `listener` placement?

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... valueChangeListener="#{bean.listener}">
    <f:selectItems ... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` will only be invoked when the form is submitted **and** the submitted value is different from the initial value. It's thus not invoked when *only* the HTML DOM `change` event is fired. If you would like to submit the form during the HTML DOM `change` event, then you'd need to add another `<f:ajax/>` without a listener(!) to the input component. It will cause a form submit which processes only the current component (as in `execute="@this"`).

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeListener}">
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

---

When using `<f:ajax listener>` instead of `valueChangeListener`, it would by default executed during the HTML DOM `change` event already. Inside `UICommand` components and input components representing a checkbox or radiobutton, it would be by default executed during the HTML DOM `click` event only.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.ajaxListener}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

---

Another major difference is that the `valueChangeListener` method is invoked during the end of the `PROCESS_VALIDATIONS` phase. At that moment, the submitted value is not been updated in the model yet. So you cannot get it by just accessing the bean property which is bound to the input component's `value`. You need to get it by `ValueChangeEvent#getNewValue()`. The old value is by the way also available by `ValueChangeEvent#getOldValue()`.

```
public void changeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    // ...
}
```

---

The `<f:ajax listener>` method is invoked during `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase. At that moment, the submitted value is already been updated in the model. You can just get it by directly accessing the bean property which is bound to the input component's `value`.

```
private Object value; // +getter+setter.

public void ajaxListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println(value); // Look, (new) value is already set.
}
```

---

Also, if you would need to update *another* property based on the submitted value, then it would fail when you're using `valueChangeListener` as the updated property *can* be overridden by the submitted value during the subsequent `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` phase. That's exactly why you see in old JSF 1.x applications/tutorials/resources that a `valueChangeListener` is in such construct been used in combination with `immediate="true"` and `FacesContext#renderResponse()` to prevent that from happening. After all, using the `valueChangeListener` to execute business actions has actually always been a hack/workaround.

Summarized: Use the `valueChangeListener` only if you need to intercept on the actual value change itself. I.e. you're actually interested in *both* the old and the new value (e.g. to log them).

```
public void changeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    changeLogger.log(event.getOldValue(), event.getNewValue());
}
```

Use the `<f:ajax listener>` only if you need to execute a business action on the newly changed value. I.e. you're actually interested in *only* the new value (e.g. to populate a second dropdown).

```
public void ajaxListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    selectItemsOfSecondDropdown = populateItBasedOn(selectedValueOfFirstDropdown);
}
```

If you're actually also interested in the old value while executing a business action, then fall back to `valueChangeListener`, but queue it to the `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase.

```
public void changeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() != PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
        event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
        event.queue();
        return;
    }

    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    System.out.println(newValue.equals(value)); // true
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @BalusC, is there a reason not to obtain the _old_ value from the backing object in the setter before setting it to the _new_ value that is passed in?  Something like this: `logger.trace( "setting changeTypes from {} to {}", this.changeTypes, changeTypes );`.  It seems like you could use the old and new values obtained in that fashion to do _business logic_ directly in the setter as well as simple logging, but I don't know if this would cause side effects...

Comment: @BalusC is it possible to also get the changed value through AjaxBehaviorEvent? I have <h:selectManyListbox that is chained to other components and will like to use the changed (Added/Removed) to perform some action

Comment: @Paullo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750185/ajax-for-valuechangelistener/

Comment: Thanks @BalusC But i dont think ValueChangeListener will fit in my case as I have some execute and render values as shown <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="tests" execute="@this" listener="#{testController.processTimeTable}" />

Comment: I indeed found this answer helpfull regarding my question that I posted today  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926653/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-view-requestbeanpage2-nouvelledateaction?noredirect=1#comment57586949_34926653, I changed  System.out.println("dateValueChanged : "+ date.toString()); with System.out.println("dateValueChanged : "+ event.getNewValue());

Comment: @Paullo Store the value progammatically in an instance attribute of the bean before change. At the next change you will have the value.

Answer (score 9):

for the first fragment (ajax listener attribute):

The "listener" attribute of an ajax tag is a method that is called on the server side every time the ajax function happens on the client side. For instance, you could use this attribute to specify a server side function to call every time the user pressed a key

but the second fragment (valueChangeListener) :

The ValueChangeListener will only be called when the form is submitted, not when the value of the input is changed

*you might like to view this [handy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802483/1019741)