# Change inputText value from listener method

Tags: jsf-2

I have an inputText:

```
<h:inputText id="result" value="#{guessNumber.result}"/>
```

and another inputText:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{guessNumber.named}" onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{guessNumber.processValueChange}"/>
```

and inside the processValueChange method, I added the following line:

```
result = "hello";
```

but the displayed value of "result" inputText remains unchainged, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:
Instead of binding the *value* attribute of the inputText to a String property (result) inside the bean, I bound the inputText to UIInput property inside the bean:

```
<h:inputText id="result" binding="#{guessNumber.result}"/>
```

and in the bean:

```
private UIInput result = null;
```

this lets the listener method modify the inputText *value* directly, instead of modifying the property that is bound to the *value* attribute of the inputText:

```
result.setValue("Hello");
```

Thanks for every one tried to solve my problem.

Answer (score 13):

The `valueChangeListener` method isn't intended to make changes to the model this way. It's intented to listen on the actual change of the model value, at exactly the moment where you have a hand of *both* the old and new model value. For example, to perform some logging. It runs at the end of the validations phase, right *before* the update model values phase. So any changes which you make to the model values *yourself* inside the listener method would be overridden during the update model values phase.

You need a `<f:ajax listener>` instead. This runs during the invoke action phase, which is *after* the update model values phase.

```
<h:outputText id="result" value="#{guessNumber.result}" />
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{guessNumber.named}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{guessNumber.namedChanged}" render="result" />
</h:inputText>
```

*(note that I've removed the `onchange="submit()"` JavaScript handler!)*

with

```
public void namedChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    result = "Hello, you entered " + named;
}
```

*(the argument is optional; if you don't need it, just omit it)*

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)

Comment: Hello BalusC, I tried your suggestion but still not working, nothing happens when "name" inputText loses focus, the only line included inside namedChanged method is: result = "hello";

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Binding is kind of tricky and might get you into trouble.