# jsf inputText only displayed value when is readonly true or outputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I have a `h:inputText` with `valueChangeListener`, when the user type some code another `h:inputText` display data from MySQL about that code, the `valueChangeListener` works but the second `h:inputText` not displayed the value and only do it when I set the readonly attribute or I change the component to `h:outputText`

my facelets page is:

```
<h:form id="idFacturacion">  
<rich:panel>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="FACTURACION AL CLIENTE" />
</f:facet>
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
<h:outputText value="Cedula: " />
<h:inputText value="#{facturaBean.encFactura.cedula}" onchange="submit();" valueChangeListener="#{facturaBean.processValueChange}" />
<h:outputText value="Nombre: " />
<h:inputText value="#{facturaBean.encFactura.nombre_cli}" />
</h:panelGrid>
</rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

facturaBean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FacturaBean {
    private EncFactura encFactura = new EncFactura();
    //getter and setter
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event){
        String ced = event.getNewValue().toString();
        try{
            //do the database thing
            if(resultSet.next()){
                encFactura.setNombre_cli(resultSet.getString("nombre_cli"));
            }else{
                encFactura.setNombre_cli("");
            }
        }catch(SQLException error){
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Hubo un error SQL."));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob Gilmore i'm new in this and i don't speak english

Comment: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645593/change-inputtext-value-from-listener-method

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974989/possible-to-execute-valuechangelistener-for-pinputtext-without-hitting-ent

Comment: You need add id for second `inputText` and rerender it using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see

- [Change inputText value from listener method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645593/)… and
- [Possible to execute `valueChangeListener` for `p:inputText` without hitting `enter` key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974989/)

May I suggest using ajax?
Here is a primefaces example but you could apply to richfaces..

```
 <h:inputText value="#{facturaBean.stringOne}" >    
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{facturaBean.processValueChange}" update="strTwo"/> </h:inputText> <h:outputText value="Nombre: " /> 
    <h:inputText id="strTwo" value="#{facturaBean.stringTwo}" /> 
</h:panelGrid>

private String stringOne= "";
private String stringTwo= "";


public void processValueChange(){
    stringTwo = stringOne;
}
```

With getters etc.. basically on change, fires off to ajax, you do your database call etc, then it returns the response and updates your other input field, it's a much cleaner way than trying to submit forms etc..

Also are you sure you want session scope?