# Does the valueChangeListener method create a new bean instance each time?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, valuechangelistener

I've a `<p:selectOneMenu>` with `String` entries and a `valueChangeListener` on it.

View:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myLdapEntry.oneMenuselectedValue}" effect="fade" style="font-size:12px;"
    valueChangeListener="#{myLdapEntry.menuValueChanged}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{treeBean.objclasslist}" var="objclass"
    itemLabel="#{objclass}" itemValue="#{objclass}" />
    <p:column>   
        #{o}  #{objclass}
    </p:column>
    <f:ajax event="change" render=":form:objclassAttrsValstab" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Model:

```
List<String> objectClassList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void menuValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
    String newValue = vce.getNewValue().toString();
    objectClassList.add(newValue);
    System.out.println(objectClassList);
}
```

I would like to remember every previously seledted item in the `objectClassList`. But the problem is that it always contains only the last selected item and not the items before that. I've even tried with a `Vector` instead of a `List`, but still have the same result.

I think that the `valueChangeListener` method creates a new bean instance each time so that the `objectClassList` is reinitialized each time.

Is this true? How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why don't you just put a debug breakpoint or a logging statement in the constructor to verify if this is the case? What scope is your bean been placed in?

Comment: i didnt had any scope so it was the default : the requestScope , thank u BalusC !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can indeed happen if the bean is request scoped. Every HTTP **request** would then create a brand new bean instance. Simple as that. If you need to have the same bean instance while interacting on the same view, then it should be placed in the view scope instead.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyLdapEntry {
   // ... 
}
```

This problem is totally unrelated to whether you use `valueChangeListener` or not.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `valueChangeListener` isn't entirely the right place to perform business actions and model value manipulations. Rather use `<p:ajax listener>` instead of `valueChangeListener` (and `<f:ajax>`).

```
<p:ajax listener="#{myLdapEntry.menuValueChanged}" update=":form:objclassAttrsValstab" />
```

with

```
public void menuValueChanged() {
    objectClassList.add(oneMenuselectedValue);
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)