# Select Item from many menu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Ok I have a simple many menu in wich I call a listener

```
<p:selectManyMenu style="width: 100%;" id="cmbsectores" valueChangeListener="#{mbcompletado.removeItem}">                                            
      <f:selectItems value="#{mbcompletado.sectores}"/>    
      <f:ajax update="@this"/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

I am looking the way I can use the ValueChangeEvent pass as parameter to detect which item was selected?? 
So I can use my business logic!

Do i need to use ajax tag? I found an itemSelect event in primeface, framework which I am using, but it only works on charts components!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using PrimeFaces use `p:ajax` instead of `f:ajax`. The `event` is already set to the appropriate event (valueChanged).

To detect the selected values of the `selectManyMenu` the `value` attribute is necessary:

```
<p:selectManyMenu style="width: 100%;" id="cmbsectores"
    value="#{mbcompletado.selectedSectores}">                                            
    <f:selectItems value="#{mbcompletado.sectores}"/>    
    <p:ajax/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

You can remove the valueChangeListener listener altogether.

For a more complete example see [SelectManyMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyMenu.jsf).

**EDIT:**

In your backing bean `mbcompletado.selectedSectores` should point to a collection of the same type like your `mbcompletado.sectores`. For example, if your `sectores` is a `List` of `TypeA`, `selectedSectores` should be also a `List` of the same type (`TypeA`).

Similar backing-bean structure can be found in the following example [SelectManyCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyCheckbox.jsf).

Comment: So that example omits the bean.java cuze its too simple or it is not needed!?

Comment: @DavidAgustinAlmanzaGaitan correct, the backing in that example has two collections of the same type with appropriate getters/setter. I edited my answer.

Comment: but how would that ajax method event be if I expect to receive some sort of selectedItem index for example?

Comment: @DavidAgustinAlmanzaGaitan in that case `value="#{mbcompletado.selectedSectores}"` should point to the list of the selected indexes.

Comment: @DavidAgustinAlmanzaGaitan have you succeed with detecting the selected items or you are still facing the same problem?

Comment: yes, I can't get the selected item in the manymenu, yet. Still trying to solve this around!

Comment: @DavidAgustinAlmanzaGaitan both answers are providing information about the selection. What do you mean by you can't get the selected item, is there any error message? Have you tried to set a breakpoint in the setter of `selectedSectores` list and debug your project?

Comment: Ok I need a to feed a String list form a input txt but now I am using a collector to charge that list in to a gridTable, it's a component  more practical and suitable. But it seems very odd that a manymenu does not handle the selected items and have a functionality like the itemSelectEvent from the chart components!

Comment: @DavidAgustinAlmanzaGaitan this is false. the manyMenu can handle the selected item(s). whenever you select a new item in the manyMenu the setter of the `value` is called containing the list of the selected items in the manyMenu, also if you attach a `listener` on `p:ajax` it will be called whenever a selection happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `<f:ajax listener>` (or in this case better `<p:ajax listener>`) method instead. The `ValueChangeListener` serves an entirely different purpose and should only be used when you're really interested in *both* the old and new value, not when you're only interested in the new value.

E.g.

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.selectedSectors>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableSectors}"/>    
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.selectedSectorsChanged}" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

with

```
private List<String> selectedSectors;
private List<String> availableSectors;

public void selectedSectorsChanged() {
    System.out.println("Selected sectors are: " + selectedSectors); // Look, JSF has already set it.
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)