# Possible to execute `valueChangeListener` for `p:inputText` without hitting `enter` key?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'd like to execute `valueChangeListener` for `p:inputText` when user changes text and inputText looses focus (onchange). Is this possible? For now it only executed after I press return.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` method requires a form submit to be invoked. This is a server side event, not a client side event or so. Just changing and blurring the input does by default not submit the form at all. Bring in a `<p:ajax>` to do the magic.

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.inputValue}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.inputChanged}">
    <p:ajax />
</p:inputText>
```

However, although [you didn't tell anything about the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that this is the right solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I just wanted to mention that the `valueChangeListener` is more than often the wrong tool for the job you had in mind. Use `<p:ajax listener>` instead.

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.inputValue}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.inputChanged}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Note that this would then make it possible to pass method arguments by EL 2.2, which would immediately then answer the possible underlying functional requirement of [your other — actually pretty poor — question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975026/possible-to-pass-pinputtext-parameters-via-f-param).

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.inputValue}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.inputChanged('arg1', 'arg2')}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Also note that this might not be the solution at all if you're actually interested on the entered value; you could just access the `inputValue` property directly.

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)