# Possible to pass `p:inputText` parameters via `f:param`?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

It seems to me that `p:inputText` does not support sending parameters via `f:param`. Is this true?

If yes, how could I pass the parameters?

**In more details**
I have a list of inputText fields generated via:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{EncryptionBean.epList}" var="item">
  <p:column>
  ...
     <p:inputText value="#{item.APID}" valueChangeListener="#{EncryptionBean.listenerApid}">
         <f:param value="#{item.presetName}" name="whoLaunched"/>
     <p:inputText>
  </p:column>    
<(p:dataTable>
```

When I catch the value change listener, I need to know which of the `EncryptionBean.epList` does the `inputText` belong to. I usualy do this with:

```
ExternalContext ec; 
...
String value = (String)ec.getRequestParameterMap().get("whoLaunched");
```

...but it does not work for `inputText` (as it worked for `commandLink` for example).

Basically, how do I pass `item.presetName` together with itemText value (`item.APID`) to the listener? I need to save those 2 in the map.

Comment: In future questions, try to elaborate the concrete functional requirement in detail instead of asking a rhetorical question about a "possible solution". Stack Overflow is generally not interested in answering Yes-No questions which can easily be answered yourself.

Comment: Added more details, could you have a look? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

xhtml:

```
<p:inputText value="#{item.APID}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{EncryptionBean.listenerApid( item.presetName, item.APID )}"/>              
</p:inputText>
```

java bean:

```
public void listenerApid( String presetName, String typedAPID )
{       
    // Do something with values.
}
```

Ubelievable how easy it is to pass those values, just use `ajax listener` with arguments instead of `valueChangeListener`.

Comment: Note that this was been answered in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974989/possible-to-execute-valuechangelistener-for-pinputtext-without-hitting-ent

Comment: Yes, that's where I picked up the `(arg1, arg2)` idea. Thanks for that. If you want to write a more elaborate answer, I'll be glad to mark that one as accepted here too?