# Primefaces: how to update a p:inputText with a parameter on the setter?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page where the user must input grading for a number of categories. The categories are retrieved dynamically from a database (there are different user types, and for each type you get different categories). As there are subcategories, I have implemented it using <p:treeTable>.
I have the grades stored in a map, with the category id as the key and the grade as the value:

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> detailedGrades
```

The problem is how to get and set the grade for each category using <p:inputText>, because the category id has to be a parameter in that. I have managed to do the getter like this:

```
<p:inputText id="cat" value="#registerCandidateGradeBean.getGradeForCat(gradingCat.pkCertGradeCategoryId)}"/>
```

and in the bean:

```
public Double getGradeForCat(int catID){
    return detailedGrades.containsKey(catID) ? detailedGrades.get(catID) : null;
}
```

This displays the value in the input field OK, but I don't know how to set the value when the user changes it. I tried with <p:ajax listener> as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975026/possible-to-pass-pinputtext-parameters-via-fparam), where I set

```
<p:ajax listener="#{registerCandidateGradeBean.setGradeForCat1(gradingCat.pkCertGradeCategoryId)}"/>
```

and in the bean:

```
public void setGradeForCat1(int catID){
    System.out.println(catID);
}
```

but whenever I change the input value I get a "javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation" exception. I tried to use a valueChangeListener on the inputText

```
<p:inputText id="cat" value="#registerCandidateGradeBean.getGradeForCat(gradingCat.pkCertGradeCategoryId)}" 
valueChangeListener="#{registerCandidateGradeBean.setGradeForCat}"/>
```

and in the bean:

```
public void setGradeForCat(ValueChangeEvent e){
    System.out.println("called");
    //System.out.println(catID);
    System.out.println(e.getNewValue());
}
```

but it never gets called. (I have tried both setGradeForCat(ValueChangeEvent e) and setGradeForCat(ValueChangeEvent e, int catID)).
Any ideas?

Forgot to mention: we are using primefaces 5.3.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that you use value="#registerCandidateGradeBean.getGradeForCat(gradingCat.pkCertGradeCategoryId)}" in the input component.
This makes jsf looking for a getter and setter which is called getgetGradeForCat and setgetGradeForCat.