# I need a mask for money inputs in primefaces inputMask component

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces

My problem is that I can't find a working mask that matches money inputs for InputMask component in primefaces. I use primefaces 4.0.  I want to have the possibility to enter values like :

```
 1234.56
 1234.50
 2.80
 120
 120.00
```

I need 2 digits after the comma and a maximum of 8 digits before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

if you could specify the custom format in regex or mask (eg. regexMask="R$########.###,##"), could be better enough. ;)

You can also use the following url for your help:

```
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3507
```

PrimeFaces team is still working on improving the filter for it.

Thanks&Regards,

Comment: I appreciate your answer SHAYAN but i'm trying to avoid the use of primefaces extension. and for the use of Regex or Mask i tried different masks but it doesn't take all above cases into consideration.

Comment: Sir, the probelm is that the PrimeFaces team is still working on input masks, I learnt that in mailing list on google. That is one of the working ways that helped me too, so I told you. :)

Comment: I didn't know that PF's team is still working on this component. Thank you for that information at least it'll save me a lot of time of meaningless search on masks hhh. Is it possible to use events in primefaces to customize inputs?

Comment: You are most welcome.
Well I am not totally aware of how to do it, but sometimes ago, I faced a problem of the same kind for the calendar thing and the following post seemed making some sense:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974989/possible-to-execute-valuechangelistener-for-pinputtext-without-hitting-ent

See if that can help you. :)