# p:dialog closes when valueChangeListener is invoked

Tags: jsf, dialog, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a `<p:dialog>` which contains a `<h:selectOneMenu>` with a `valueChangeListener`. Here's the relevant code:

```
<p:dialog> 
    <h:form>
        <div>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{itemController.itemId}" valueChangeListener="#{itemController.chkItemType}" onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItems value="#{itemController.itemsList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu> 
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

When it is called, the dialog get closed. I would like to keep it open and only close it on cancel button. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behaviour. The `onchange="submit()"` which you've there submits the entire form synchronously, causing a complete page reload.

You should be using ajax instead to perform the submit. Replace the `onchange` attribute by just this tag

```
<f:ajax />
```

inside the `<h:selectOneMenu>`. This way the form will be submitted asynchronously, with by default no page reload at all.

Depending on the concrete functional requirement, [which you didn't tell anything about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you do probably also not need a `valueChangeListener` at all, but rather a `<f:ajax listener>`.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{itemController.chkItemType}" />
```

If you'd like to update some parts of the page on successful execution of the ajax request, use its `render` attribute.

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/11883021#11883021)