# Ajax for valueChangeListener

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, onchange

I'm using the `p:ajax` listener to handle value change events (because `valueChangeListener` is launched on form submit):

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.onNameChanged}"/>
```

Handle method:

```
public void onNameChanged(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
```

The problem is, I can't find in `AjaxBehaviorEvent` nor its class hierarchy the place to read the **old value** of the input. Neither could I find hint in google, how to get the old value...

How to access the old value in the `p:ajax onChange` event?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> *The problem is, I can't find in AjaxBehaviorEvent nor its class hierarchy the place to read the old value of the input. Neither could I find hint in google, how to get the old value...*

Use a `valueChangeListener`.

---

> *Unfortunatelly, valueChangeListener is invoked before p:ajax, so I don't have actual data from forms in that method, so in theory I could use valueChangeListener to remember the old value and then wait for p:ajax to process...*

Queue the value change event to the invoke application phase.

```
public void valueChangeListenerMethod(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() != PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
        event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
        event.queue();
        return;
    }

    // Do your original job here. 
    // It will only be invoked when current phase ID is INVOKE_APPLICATION.
}
```

Comment: +1, Someone should do "BalusC IS AWESOME" video (just like "PEOPLE ARE AWESOME" videos)

Comment: Bauke you're amazing guy :D You just saved me hours of head scratching.

Comment: As usual BalusC has solved my problem for me years before I had it.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you for this answer, 'JSF is religion-BalusC is god.'

Answer (score 7):

The ValueChangeListener should work this way:

The view:

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{sessionBean.hello}" 
               valueChangeListener="#{sessionBean.valueChangeListener}">
    <p:ajax/>
  </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

The bean:

```
public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {
  System.out.println("valueChangeListener invoked:" 
                      + " OLD: " + e.getOldValue() 
                      + " NEW: " + e.getNewValue());
}
```

The above code will print if I change the text field from "hello" to "world":

> valueChangeListener invoked: OLD: hello NEW: world

Comment: do you know how to made also the bean changes visible to the server code? with p:ajax I have the process option, to send the UI control's content, with that way they are in state from last submit...

Comment: @lechlukasz: Take a look at BalusC's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

1. Implement the value change event in your bean

   ```
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent e){
    //foo the bar
    }
   ```
2. Define a `valueChangeListener` on your selection component

   ```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{yourBean.value}" onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="{#yourBean.processValueChange}">
   ```

   The key piece there is the `submit()` bit that processes the enclosing form on change of the value. You can then `getNewValue()` and `getOldValue()` as necessary.

EDIT: Now that I think about it, I see no reason why you cannot leave your setup as-is and simply define the `valueChangeListener`. It should still be processed during the `change` event in the `<p:ajax/>`, in fact, it will be processed before the listener for the ajax event itself.

Comment: No, submit can't be done (because of validation) and the changes must be visible to other components after changing the field, so it's not a solution)

Comment: @lechlukasz: You can do a partial submit as stated in the "EDIT"-part of kolossus answer. Then the valueChangeListener will be invoked and you can access the old and the new value. All other form elements will not be evaluated/processed (unless you put it in the `execute` attribute of the ajax call.)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, valueChangeListener is invoked before p:ajax, so I don't have actual data from forms in that method, so in theory I could use valueChangeListener to remember the old value and then wait for p:ajax to process...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
public void onNameChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
 {
    String myVal = (String) ((UIOutput) event.getSource()).getValue();
    System.out.println("myVal: " + myVal);
 }
```

Comment: OP is interested in "**old** value" as it was *before* update model values phase has taken place. The ajax listener, however, runs *after* update model values phase. See the currently accepted answer for the proper approach.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround is possible (tested with Primefaces 10):

```
<p:inputText id="name" value="bean.name">
     <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="name"
             listener="#{bean.onNameChanged}"
             onstart="cfg.ext={params:[{name:'oldValue', value:'#{bean.name}'}]};"/>
</p:inputText>
```

`update="name"` is important, to get each time the new value into the javascript event handler.

Bean Method:

```
public void onNameChanged(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    String oldValue = getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                      .get("oldValue");
    //Do with oldValue, whatever you want
}
```