# Primefaces valueChangeListener or <p:ajax listener not firing for p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.4.2.

I have the following in my JSF page

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="emp" value="#{mymb.emp.employeeName}" 
        valueChangeListener="#{mymb.handleChange}" 
        required="true"
        style="width: 150px;">
    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" 
            itemLabel="Please  Select"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{mymb.employeeList}" var="emp"
            itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}"
            itemValue="#{emp.employeeNumber}"/>
    <p:ajax update="sublist"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and in ManagedBean

```
public void handleChange(ValueChangeEvent event){  
    System.out.println("here "+event.getNewValue());
}
```

The problem is `valueChangeListener` is not firing, i.e. `handleChange` method is not getting invoked. I tried with the following, but it is not working either.

```
<p:ajax update="sublist"  listener="#{mymb.handleChange}" />
```

Separate JSF page:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:head>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="form">                      
                <p:panelGrid columns="6">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Employees" for="employees" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="employees"
                            value="#{mymb.employeesList}" 
                            required="true">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{mymb.employeesList}" var="emp"
                                itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" />
                        <p:ajax listener="#{mymb.handleChange}"   />  
                    </p:selectOneMenu>                  
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: valueChangeListener will not start when the value was changed, but when the form was submited

Comment: @lechlukasz What about `<p:ajax listener` or what is the best option to invoke Managedbean and get the selected value if `valueChangeListener` will not fire when value is changed?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/

Comment: @BalusC Problem is `<p:ajax listener="#{my.handleChange}` is not firing. My selectOneMenu is inside a `<p:dialog` Does this cause any problem?

Comment: That can indeed cause a problem if it does not have its own form while it's relocated to end of `<body>`.

Comment: @BalusC Dialog form has its own <h:form> </h:form> tags

Comment: @Polppan, you might want to check your browser's developer console to confirm that a)the request is being fired properly b)there are no hidden validation or conversion errors. The `<h:form/>` is *inside* the dialog right?

Comment: @kolossus I checked in firebug console and I found the following in response `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[1693086094126573545:4149873601205987934]]></update></changes></partial-response>`.  my dialog is wrapped inside <h:form/> </h:form>

Comment: @Polppan, the response indicates the request is certainly being sent to the server and a valid response received. Put the `<h:form/>` inside the dialog instead, i.e. the dialog should wrap the form. As a precaution, add `appendToBody="false"` to the dialog

Comment: @kolossus I have put form inside dialog and added appendToBody="false", however still handleChange method is not getting invoked.

Comment: Interesting. Now I'm just guessing. PF had some issues leading up to V3.4 with `noSelectionOption`.Remove that attribute and see what happens

Comment: @kolossus I have removed noSelectionOption, still didn't work. I have removed all other code and all I have is selectOneMenu in a seperate JSF page and still it didn't work. I have put my code as Update 1 by editing my question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to use `valueChangeListener`, you need to submit the form every time a new option is chosen. Something like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{mymb.employee}" onchange="submit()"
                 valueChangeListener="#{mymb.handleChange}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{mymb.employeesList}" var="emp"
                   itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeID}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

public void handleChange(ValueChangeEvent event){  
    System.out.println("New value: " + event.getNewValue());
}
```

Or else, if you want to use `<p:ajax>`, it should look like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{mymb.employee}" >
    <p:ajax listener="#{mymb.handleChange}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{mymb.employeesList}" var="emp"
                   itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeID}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

private String employeeID;

public void handleChange(){  
    System.out.println("New value: " + employee);
}
```

One thing to note is that in your example code, I saw that the `value` attribute of your `<p:selectOneMenu>` is `#{mymb.employeesList}` which is the same as the `value` of `<f:selectItems>`. The `value` of your `<p:selectOneMenu>` should be similar to my examples above which point to a single employee, not a list of employees.

Comment: J4mes Thanks it worked, except for one thing, in ManagedBean handleChange method value of employee.employeeName is null. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: It should be `employee.getEmployeeName()`. I edited my answer

Comment: Even that comes as null

Comment: hmmm.... there shouldn't be any problems at all. Did you import the right package? If you're using `@ManagedBean` annotation, you need to import `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` instead of `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.

Comment: If the problem persists, you should create a dummy page with a dummy managed bean containing a property like `private String testString` and a `selectOneMenu` with dummy options. Try and find out if you still lack knowledge about some particular aspects.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that you need a converter to get a full Employee :P. I edited my answer to get the employeeID instead of a full Employee.

Comment: With converter it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's better to force submit for valueChangeListener with p:ajax too. I.e. you can add `<p:ajax />` without listener or anything - this will trigger an AJAX-request.

Answer (score 16):

The `valueChangeListener` is only necessary, if you are interested in both the old *and* the new value.

If you are only interested in the new value, the use of `<p:ajax>` or `<f:ajax>` is the better choice.

There are several possible reasons, why the ajax call won't work. First you should change the method signature of the handler method: drop the parameter. Then you can access your managed bean variable directly:

```
public void handleChange(){  
  System.out.println("here "+ getEmp().getEmployeeName());
}
```

At the time, the listener is called, the new value is already set. (Note that I implicitly assume that the el expression `mymb.emp.employeeName` is correctly backed by the corresponding getter/setter methods.)

Comment: Matt Initially I had only  `<p:ajax listener="#{my.handleChange}"  update="sublist"  /> ` , but still handleChange method is not getting invoked at all.  `public void handleChange(){  `

Comment: Does it work if you add  `process="@form"` to the ajax call?

Comment: My selectOneMenu is inside a `<p:dialog` Does this cause any problem?

Comment: Maybe. Try it without the dialog.

Comment: Matt I have removed all other code and all I have is selectOneMenu in a seperate JSF page and still it didn't work. I have put my code as Update 1 by editing my question.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution is to mix valueChangeListener, ajax and process:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="employees" value="#{employees}" columns="1" layout="grid" valueChangeListener="#{mybean.fireSelection}"   >
    <f:selectItems var="employee" value="#{employeesSI}" />
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" immediate="true" process="@this"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Method in mybean is just :

```
public void fireSelection(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    log.debug("New: "+event.getNewValue()+", Old: "+event.getOldValue());
}
```

Like this, valueChangeEvent is very light !

PS: Works fine with PrimeFaces 5.0

Comment: Indeed, adding an explicit `process="@this"` on the `<p:ajax>`seems to do the trick of firing the `ValueChangeEvent` (using PF 6.2 here). That's a bit surprising, though, because [PrimeFaces documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/ajaxProcessing) (as of PF 8.0, but also for older versions) explicitly says: _Note that default value for `process` option is `@this` already for `p:ajax` as stated in `AjaxBehavior` documentation, it is explicitly defined here to give a better understanding of how partial processing works._...

Answer (score 10):

```
<p:ajax listener="#{my.handleChange}" update="id of component that need to be rerender after change" process="@this" />



import javax.faces.component.UIOutput;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

public void handleChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent vce){  
  String name= (String) ((UIOutput) vce.getSource()).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

All can be defined as in `f:ajax` attiributes.

i.e.

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="employees" value="#{mymb.employeesList}" required="true">
         <f:selectItems value="#{mymb.employeesList}" var="emp" itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" />
         <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{mymb.handleChange}" execute="@this" render="@all" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**event**: it can be normal DOM Events like `click`, or `valueChange`

**execute**: *This is a space separated list of client ids of components that will participate in the "execute" portion of the Request Processing Lifecycle.*

**render**: *The clientIds of components that will participate in the "render" portion of the Request Processing Lifecycle.* After action done, you can define which components should be refresh. Id, IdList or these keywords can be added: `@this`, `@form`, `@all`, `@none`.

You can reache the whole attribute list by following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html

Comment: This is (almost) in the accepted and highly upvoted answer. Maybe suggest a small textual improvement on that one

Comment: @Kukeltje you are right, however there are some additional attiributes above example which I share: event, execute and render. By these attributes you can change the behaviour of f:ajax. And additionally there is a brief explanation of these documentation on the link. Accepted answer could not help me, however, another similar questions' answer which I copied here, help me about my problems. Thats why I wanted to share and maybe help others having same trouble like me...

Answer (score 2):

Try using p:ajax with event attribute,

Answer (score 2):

My problem were that we were using spring securyty, and the previous page doesn't call the page using faces-redirect=true, then the page show a java warning, and the control doesn't fire the change event.

Solution:
The previous page must call the page using, faces-redirect=true

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

It can be used inside the dialog, but the dialog can´t be inside any componet such as panels, accordion, etc.