# Enable/Disable SelectOneMenu of primefaces using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to JSF and Primefaces.
I am building a xhtml page in which i have two selectonemenu of primefaces.I wanted to enable or disable second selectonemenu depending on the value selected by user in first selectonemenu.
For enable/disable i wrote Java Script in the page as i wanted to do it at client side, but i dont know how to call java script function in the primefaces component.

Code Sample

```
        <h:head>
        <style type="text/css">
    .ui-widget,.ui-widget .ui-widget {
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }
    </style>
        <script>
            function disableOneMenu() {
                alert("In Disable One Menu Function...");
                var clickedGroup = document.getElementById('groupOneMenu').value;
                alert("Selected Value " + clickedGroup);
                if (clickedGroup == "Designation") {
                    document.getElementById('designation').disabled = true;
                    alert("Location One Menu Disabled...");
                } 
            }
        </script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/redmond/skin.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="30"
                    header="HCV : Peer Group Analysis" resizable="true">
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit id="contentLayout" position="west" size="200">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Analyse for values of attribute: " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="groupOneMenu" value="#{userInput.groupAttr}"
                            style="font-size:18;font-weight:bold;color:blue;width:100">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{userInput.groupAttrList}" />
                            <p:ajax event="valueChange" actionListener="disableOneMenu" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <h:outputText value="Designation: " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="designatinoOneMenu"
                            value="#{userInput.designation}"
                            style="font-size:18;font-weight:bold;color:blue;width:100">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{userInput.designationList}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                       </h:panelGrid>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Please help, hw can i use java script in xhtml page..

Thanks..

Comment: You try `<p:ajax oncomplete="disableOneMenu()"` for the first selectonemenu.

Comment: Thanks.its working..but is there any problem in my java script function because when i change the value of firstselectmenu, first alert box pop up..but it is not poping up second alert box and not disabling the second selectonemenu..

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript API for PrimeFaces component is mostly documented. There are `disable()` and `enable()` methods on DOM variable.

You need to give the name to this variable using `widgetVar` attribute:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="myMenu" widgetVar="myMenuWidget" ... />
```

You can than call in JavaScript:

```
myMenuWidget.disable();
```

`widgetVar` must be different than ID! IE is using the same namespace for ids and global JS variables (as opposed to FireFox).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `disabled` attributes of `<h:selectOneMenu>` to do the same. you don't need to use java script.

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{test.visible}"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{test.valuChangeHandler}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{test.opList}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
       <h:selectOneMenu disabled="#{!test.visible}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{test.testList}"/>
       </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and the Bean can be written as:

```
private boolean visible = false;
public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;

}
//Other Codes
public void valuChangeHandler(ValueChangeEvent changeEvent){

    if(changeEvent.getNewValue().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("test1"))
        setVisible(true);
}
```

See if this helps!

Comment: The variable `visible` is set to false, and when you select a particular option from the first drop down menu, it enables the second drop down. Or else the second one remains disabled from the beginning. Now using this technique you can do what you wanted.:)

Comment: Hey..its working..thanks a lot...but i wanted to do it with prime faces. With faces tag (<h>) its working properly but its not working with primefaces tag (<p >)..is there any problem with selectonemenu of primefaces?? I am using like this <p:selectOneMenu id="groupOneMenu" value="#{userInput.groupAttr}"
      style="font-size:18;font-weight:bold;color:blue;width:100" 
      valueChangeListener="#{userInput.valuChangeHandler}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">

Comment: @Abhay: May be this Example Article can Help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956261/primefaces-valuechangelistener-or-pajax-listener-not-firing-for-pselectonemen

Answer (score 0):

try it!

```
<script>
  function disableOneMenu() {

    PF('designatinoOneMenuWV').disabled();
  }
</script>

<p:selectOneMenu id="groupOneMenu" value="#{userInput.groupAttr}" 
      style="font-size:18;font-weight:bold;color:blue;width:100" onchange="disableOneMenu()">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{userInput.groupAttrList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="designatinoOneMenu" widgetVar="designatinoOneMenuWV"
      value="#{userInput.designation}" style="font-size:18;font-weight:bold;color:blue;width:100">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{userInput.designationList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```