# How to fire a ValueChangeEvent on blur for an inputtext component with primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I still have the problem that i need the old and the new value of an inputtext component on a blur event. But i don't see a way to get the blur event without the use of "p:ajax".

Are there any other ways to get the old and new value?

xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputtext value="#{myController.value}"
        valueChangeListener="#{myController.handleEvent}">
        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{myController.handleEvent}" />
    </p:inputtext>
</h:form>
```

Controller:

```
@ViewAccessScoped
@Named("myController")
public class MyController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8736461860325705841L;

    public void intervalChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        // I need the old value here!
    }

    public void intervalChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        // Here i got the old value but this listener method is not invoked on blur
    }
}
```

Comment: Found the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25390954/739253

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces valueChangeListener or <p:ajax listener not firing for p:selectOneMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956261/primefaces-valuechangelistener-or-pajax-listener-not-firing-for-pselectonemen)

Comment: Not really. Both listener are fired correctly. Look at the link which i comment. It is an answer of this ticket.