# IllegalStateException in primefaces dropdown

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a datatable which contains a dropdown, when I change the value in dropdown I am getting an exception saying IllegalStateException. 
The datatable code is shared below.

```
    <p:column width="180">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Data Type" />
        </f:facet>
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{column.dataTypeConfigNameWithId}"
           rendered="#{column.editHeaderDetails}"
           valueChangeListener="#{returnHeaderBean.dataTypeChangeAction}"
           style="width:280px">
           <f:selectItems value="#{returnHeaderBean.dataTypes}"
               var="dataType" itemLabel="#{dataTypestandardDataTypeDisplayName}"
               itemDescription="#{dataType.dataTypeDescription}"
               itemValue="#{dataType.standardDataTypeDisplayName}:                 #{dataType.id}" />
        <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="cdHTable"
          partialSubmit="true" update="@this" />
     </p:selectOneMenu>
   </p:column>
```

The Error which i am getting is

> SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default
>   task-36) java.lang.IllegalStateException  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.queueEvent(UIComponentBase.java:1052)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.queueEvent(UIComponentBase.java:1054)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:991)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)     at
>   org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:339)  at
>   org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:323)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:285)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:259)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:622)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:575)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Bean Method called

```
  public void dataTypeChangeAction(ValueChangeEvent vEvent) {
    LOGGER.info("Inside dataTypeNameChange()");
    try {
        String typeNameWithId = (String) vEvent.getNewValue();
        if (typeNameWithId != null) {
            String[] dataTypeArray = typeNameWithId.split(":");
            ReturnHeader column = (ReturnHeader) bindHdrElementsTable.getRowData();
            column.getDataTypeConfig().setStandardDataTypeDisplayName(dataTypeArray[0]);
            column.getDataTypeConfig().setId(Integer.parseInt(dataTypeArray[1]));
            column.setDataTypeConfigId(Integer.parseInt(dataTypeArray[1]));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `llegalStateException exception come when  servlet is attempting to write to the output stream (response) after the response has been committed.` Share your bean code as well.

Comment: public void dataTypeChangeAction(ValueChangeEvent vEvent) {
  LOGGER.info("Inside dataTypeNameChange()");
  try {
   String typeNameWithId = (String)vEvent.getNewValue();
   if (typeNameWithId != null) {
    String[] dataTypeArray = typeNameWithId.split(":");
    ReturnHeader column = (ReturnHeader)bindHdrElementsTable.getRowData();
 column.getDataTypeConfig().setStandardDataTypeDisplayName(
      dataTypeArray[0]);
column.getDataTypeConfig().setId(Integer.parseInt(dataTypeArray[1]));
 column.setDataTypeConfigId(Integer.parseInt(dataTypeArray[1]));
 }} catch (Exception e) {LOGGER.error(e);}}

Comment: In the bean this method is being called. do u need the whole bean?

Comment: What is the Scope of your bean?

Comment: And its all logic is in One bean or you are using different bean for this ?

Comment: the scope of the bean is sessionscoped. only one bean is being used.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. was not in office for 3 days

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956261/primefaces-valuechangelistener-or-pajax-listener-not-firing-for-pselectonemen it will resolve your problem