# Ajax doesn't set bean value and reaches listener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a problem with updating graphical image from the SelectOneListbox. What I would like to do is, when user selects an item in SelectOneListbox I would like to update image on the page in different component.

I'm trying to use Ajax for this, however even the ajax request is leaving web browser, it doesn't update the component. It passes through all phases Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1 ...  RENDER_RESPONSE 6
Unfortunately it doesn't stop at listener or it doesn't set value of the component to actual value. 
It reaches converter correctly and do conversion of the value, but that's it. Then no setting of attribute of 'editor' bean.

Here is image for better imagination :)

[image]

When I get response in my web browser it says:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">2751554428361535891:1425762350197262148</update>
        <extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "editor")
public class EditorView {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{localizationService}")
    private LocalizationService localizationService;
    private LangFlag selectedLanguage;

    public void languageUpdated(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    public void setSelectedLanguage(LangFlag selectedLanguage) {}
    public String getSelectedLanguage{};
}
```

**Converter** (with correct implementation, skipped here)

```
@FacesConverter
public class LanguageConverter implements Converter, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {}

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {}

}
```

**edit.xhtml**

```
<h:panelGroup id="countrySelectFlagPanel">
    <h:form id="translation_editor">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <p:graphicImage id="chooseLangBtn" width="22px" height="22px"
    alt="#{t.lang.englishName}" 
    library="main" name="/images/flags/var/#{editor.selectedLanguage.country.alpha2}.svg"/>
        <p:overlayPanel id="langPanel" for="chooseLangBtn" 
    showCloseIcon="true" dismissable="true"
    widgetVar="langOverlayPanel">
            <p:selectOneListbox id="langSelect" value="#{editor.selectedLanguage}" converter="#{languageConverter}" 
            var="t" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
            onclick="PF('langOverlayPanel').hide(); alert($('#translation_editor\\:langSelect_input').val())"
            valueChangeListener="#{editor.languageUpdated}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{editor.langFlagMappings}" var="l10n" 
           itemLabel="#{l10n.lang.englishName} (#{l10n.lang.nativeName})" 
           itemValue="#{l10n}"/>
                <p:ajax process="@this" listener="#{editor.languageUpdated}"  />
                <p:column><h:graphicImage width="22px" alt="#{t.lang.englishName}" 
                      library="main" name="/images/flags/var/#{t.country.alpha2}.svg"/></p:column>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{t.lang.englishName}" /></p:column>
            </p:selectOneListbox>
        </p:overlayPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Tomcat log:**

```
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:130 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@14218bd6
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/editor.xhtml'; against '/logout'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/editor.xhtml'; against '/login'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:328 - /editor.xhtml at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/editor.xhtml'; against '/javax.faces.resource/**'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/editor.xhtml'; against '/pages/secure/**'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/editor.xhtml'; against '/pages/unsecure/**'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:219 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /editor.xhtml; Attributes: [permitAll]
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@b29fd57, returned: 1
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:243 - Authorization successful
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:256 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:313 - /editor.xhtml reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:255 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'localizationService'
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG RequestLoggingPhaseListener:43 - Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:121 - Chain processed normally
2018-01-23 20:25:40 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:119 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I'm using:

- spring.security.version: 5.0.0.RELEASE
- spring.version: 5.0.2
- spring.binding.version: 1.0.6
- spring.webflow.version: 2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- primefaces.version: 6.1
- primefaces.themes.version: 1.0.10
- jsf.version: 2.2.15
- servlet.api.version: 2.5
- jstl.version: 1.2
- javax-faces.version: 2.3.3
- jsp-api.version: 2.2

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966670/3314856, basically remove process="@this".

Comment: ah no, please don't abandon me so quickly. It's just forgotten code. I'm not asking here because I'm lazy to use google. I have spent couple of hours during past few days trying to find where the problem is but with no success. I have tried it with @ this, without; I have used listener and onEvent methods. I have tried to implement stateless (RequestScoped) bean but with no success. Also <p:ajax and <f:ajax didn't solve problem... I have removed @ this and I have updated my original post, I'm including also log from the server

Comment: Please post the signature of the method being invoked in listener="#{editor.languageUpdated}" .

Comment: There was just a validation error as confirmed by the skipped phases and the ajax response. The 1st duplicate link explains how to get the validation error message. The 2nd duplicate link explains how to solve the very validation error.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for your help! I was going through the list and I have found, that I didn't implement LangFlag.equals() method... stupid silly mistake. Of course it couldn't reach any listener neither setting a new value. Since it's on it's place everything works like a charm! So duplicate is correct, with the second link.