# jsf input form value disapear on first submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 6.1. I have a problem with textarea value on first form submit. I use multiple subviews for one form. The problem is when type something into textarea, after first form submit this value disapear and not update data model. But when type again and fire submit, then this value is showing. The textarea is inside subTable in dataTable.

I tried use valueChangeListener together with ajax. This works, but when click to fast to submit, then value haven't be updated. I tried only ajax but result was the same. I tried valueChangeLister with onchange="submit()" but this not worked.  tried solution [Primefaces valueChangeListener or <p:ajax listener not firing for p:selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956261/primefaces-valuechangelistener-or-pajax-listener-not-firing-for-pselectonemen) but this not working

Textarea code

```
<h:form id="reuestForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                <p:dataTable id="edScopeTable" styleClass="form-group dataTable-space"
                             value="#{requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.getEdScopeCategories()}"
                             var="category">
                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column headerText="#{i18nMsg.ed_env_scopes_tbl_colScope_header}"/>
                        <p:column headerText="#{i18nMsg.ed_env_scopes_tbl_col_openIdConnect_header}"/>
                        <p:column headerText="#{i18nMsg.ed_env_scopes_tbl_col_reasonNeeded}"/>
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>
                <p:subTable
                        value="#{requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.getScopeReasonsByCategory(category)}"
                        var="edScope" rendered="#{requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.isCategoryInTable(category)}">
                <p:column styleClass="#{requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.calculateDiff(edScope,'cell-right')} textAlign-center">
                    <p:inputTextarea id="reason"
                                     value="#{edScope.reason}" rows="2"
                                     autoResize="false"
                                     data-disable-type="custom"
                                     styleClass="form-control #{edScope.getDiffValue('reason')}"
                                     rendered="#{edScope.edScopeConst.reasonNeeded}"
                                     label="#{i18nMsg.edScope_request_selectionTable_scope_reasonNeeded} #{edScope.edScopeConst.name}"
                                     disabled="#{requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.disableReasonField()}">
                        <f:attribute name="scope" value="#{edScope}"/>
                        <f:validateBean
                                binding="#{requestBean.validatorContainer.requiredBeanValidator}"/>
                        <p:message for="reason" display="tooltip"/>
                    </p:inputTextarea>

                    <h:outputText
                            rendered="#{not edScope.edScopeConst.reasonNeeded}"
                            value="#{i18nMsg.edScope_request_selectionTable_scope_noReasonNeeded}"/>
                </p:column>
                </p:subTable>
                </p:dataTable>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{(requestBean.request.version eq 1 and requestBean.request.stateDraft) or requestBean.isEdRequestToBePrinted() ? i18nMsg.general_mainButton_send_and_print : i18nMsg.general_mainButton_send}"
                                     id="send"
                                     update="requestForm"
                                     actionListener="#{requestBean.prepareDialog()}"
                                     oncomplete="args.validationFailed ? PF('validationFailedMessageDialog').show() : PF('readyToSendDialog').show(); jQuery(document).scrollTop(0)"
                                     title="#{requestBean.sendButtonDisabled ? i18nMsg.request_sendButtonTooltip : ''}"
                                     styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed"
                                     disabled="#{requestBean.sendButtonDisabled}" data-disable-type="custom" />

                </div>
            </h:form>
```

RequestBean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RequestBean extends PageBeanBase implements Serializable {

  private EmployeeDealerTabController employeeDealerTabController;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize() {
    employeeDealerTabController = new EmployeeDealerTabController();
  }

  public EmployeeDealerTabController getEmployeeDealerTabController() {
        return employeeDealerTabController;
  }
  public void prepareDialog() {
    // preparation before send and show dialog with confirmation send form
  }

  // rest of method

}
```

EmployerDealerTabController

```
public List<EdScopeREason> getScopeReasonsByCategory(int category) {
  if(category == 1) {
    return scopesOidcList;
  } else {
    return scopesIdentityList;
  }
}
```

EdScopeReason

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ED_SCOPE_REASON")
public class EdScopeReason extends InlineDiffBase<EdScopeReason> implements EdScopeConstBearer, Serializable, Comparable<EdScopeReason> {

    private String reason;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "REASON")
    @NotBlank(groups = RequiredValidationGroup.class, message = "{iamat.validation.general.edScopeReason.notempty}")
    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }
}
```

I have setter and getter method. When I debug this value is pass to validator but not set to component. I'm little confused why this value is not set on the first time

EDIT

I add jsf ajax to textarea input and set 5s delay on commandButton. This is some kind of workaround, but still look for better solution. When I use primefaces ajax I don't need delay, but for every primefaces ajax I display loader.gif.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="reason"
                                         ...{requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.disableReasonField()}">
                            <f:attribute name="scope" value="#{edScope}"/>
                            <f:validateBean
                                    binding="#{requestBean.validatorContainer.requiredBeanValidator}"/>
                            <p:message for="reason" display="tooltip"/>
                            <f:ajax />
                        </p:inputTextarea>
```

....

```
<p:commandButton value="#{(requestBean.request.version eq 1 and requestBean.request.stateDraft) or requestBean.isEdRequestToBePrinted() ? i18nMsg.general_mainButton_send_and_print : i18nMsg.general_mainButton_send}"
                                     id="send"
                                     update="requestForm"
                                     actionListener="#{requestBean.prepareDialog()}"
                                     oncomplete="args.validationFailed ? PF('validationFailedMessageDialog').show() : PF('readyToSendDialog').show(); jQuery(document).scrollTop(0)"
                                     title="#{requestBean.sendButtonDisabled ? i18nMsg.request_sendButtonTooltip : ''}"
                                     styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed"
                                     disabled="#{requestBean.sendButtonDisabled}" data-disable-type="custom" delay="5000" />
```

Comment: This code snippet is far from a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I updated code. I hope so now is more clear

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess there's a problem with the `value` attribute of your datatable: `requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.getEdScopeCategories()`. You're calling a getter, not a property, so I'm not sure how it will behave when first called. Try to implement a setter and a getter for this property and use `requestBean.employeeDealerTabController.edScopeCategories` as value-

Comment: Sorry, not working