# <h:selectOneMenu> value change listener invoked for all dropdowns instead of only the current

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I'm using MyFaces 1.1. I have two `<h:selectOneMenu>`s dropdowns which each point to same `valueChangeListener` method.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="d1" value="#{mybean.selectedChannel1}" 
    onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{myform.channelValuechange}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.channelList}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="d2" value="#{mybean.selectedChannel2}"
    onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{myform.channelValuechange}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.channelList}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When I change the first dropdown, then the value change listener method get fired correctly. In the method, I'm obtaining the ID of the current component as `sourceId` via `ValueChangeEvent` argument and then comparing it as follows:

```
if (sourceId.equals("d1")) {
    // ...
} else if (sourceId.equals("d2")) {
    // ...
}
```

However, my concrete problem is that `d2` block is also called when `d1` is changed.

I tried the one and other and figured that the following helped to solve the problem:

```
if (!event.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION)) {
      event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
      event.queue();
}
```

However, I don't feel like that it's the best solution. How is this caused and how can I solve it without using the above code?

Comment: Two `selectOneMenu` components have same selected value attribute. when oneis changed the second is also changed that is why action listener triggered twice.

Comment: you can change the scoop of session in `faces-config.xml` file, or switch to JSF2, in JSF2 you would set it as annotations :D

Comment: I'm working on the old application , hence it is not possible to use JSF2. I need to stick to JSF1.1

Comment: @user2511414 what differs between 1.1. and 2.x in the scope of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `onchange="submit()"` you're basically submitting the **entire** form when the current input element is changed, not only the currently changed input! In contrary to what many starters incorrectly think, there is no means of any input-specific JavaScript/Ajax magic here. As you're submitting the entire form, it would trigger the processing of *all* input components.

The `valueChangeListener` is **always** invoked when the submitted value of the input component does not `equals()` the initial model value as in the backing bean. Given that in your case both menus hit the value change listener when you change only the first one, that can only mean that the default select item value of the second menu does not `equals()` the initial model value in the backing bean.

You need to make sure that `#{mybean.selectedChannel2}` of the second menu has by default **exactly** the same value as the first item of `#{mybean.channelList}` of the second menu's list. This way the value change listener won't be invoked for the second menu when you change the first menu.

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/11883021#11883021) (just to learn what's different in JSF 2, for the case you're interested)

Comment: Thank You very much Balu!! Your answer is 100% clear, to resolve the issue. I will double check my code whether #{mybean.selectedChannel2} changed or not, when first drop down changed[:)I missed this one!!]

Comment: @Balu-You are correct.  #{mybean.selectedChannel2} value is changing when the first drop down get selected. I have fixed that bug, now ValueChangeListener is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Javel  - Am also facing the same issue. How did you fix this issue.? What is the solution for this.?

Comment: @BalusC - Is there any best solution for this.?

Comment: @Jai: upgrading to JSF 2.x and using <f:ajax listener> instead.