# JSF selectItem not calling associated ajax listener

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a drop down where default it has "choose one" and other values and labels are collected and populated from backend bean.The code is given below.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="PID" value="#{Controller.PageBean.selectedId}"  requiredMessage="Product is required" required="true" onchange="onChangeProduct();">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="choose one" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.PageBean.productList}" var="pro" itemLabel="#{pro.name}" itemValue="#{pro.id}" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{Controller.updateSelectedProduct(Controller.PageBean.selectedId)}" render="productno productName"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="productValidator"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When we change the dropdown other than "choose one" ajax function gets called and backend bean values gets changed based on selected dropdown when i choose "choose one" all values should get nullified but i am not able to reach controller at this point or the ajax function is not called please help.

Comment: Have you try putting some value in "itemValue" for "choose one"? If you want to get null value for choose one, following will be the code : <f:selectItem itemLabel="choose one" itemValue="#{null}" />

Comment: i tried that it didn't work.

Comment: If your attribute `selectedId` in your `Controller.PageBean` is `int` then `#{null}` won't do, instead use a value which means nothing was selected like `0` or `-1` instead and set that as `itemValue` instead of an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Default value of h:selectOneMenu not invoked in valueChangedListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630407/hselectonemenu-value-change-listener-invoked-for-all-dropdowns-instead-of-onl).
Although the user goes from another route the drawn conclusions are of the same concern to you! ;) (there is also a link provided by @BalusC beyond his answer which explains things quite well)