# Making valueChangeListener on h:inputHidden fire a ManagedBean method

Tags: jsf-2

My JavaScript:

```
function setJson(value) {
        document.getElementById("json").value = value;
    }
```

My XHTML:

```
<h:inputHidden id="json" value="#{indexManaged.json}" valueChangeListener="#{indexManaged.goTo('datatable')}" />
```

My ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class IndexManaged implements Serializable {

    private String json;
    public String getJson() { return json; }
    public void setJson(String json) { this.json = json; }

    public String goTo(String page) {
        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
        flash.put("json", json);
        return page + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

The scenario:

I have a Java Applet that fires the function setJson(value). But when the applet sets a new value to my inputHidden, isn't the valueChangeListener suposed to fire my ManagedBean method? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that `valueChangeListener` is fired upon form submit and not value change event (like `f:ajax`)

Comment: Please elaborate "not working" in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms. How exactly are you submitting the value to the server?

Comment: I think Daniel pointed out the problem. Is there a way to use AJAX on a inputHidden? Sorry about the poorly developed question BalusC... I improved it a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

The `valueChangeListener` isn't a client side listener. It's a server side listener which runs when the form is submitted. So, you need to submit the form as well.

Wrap it in a form

```
<h:form id="form">
```

and submit it as follows

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

Don't forget to fix the client ID of the hidden input accordingly:

```
document.getElementById("form:json").value = value;
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are cleaner ways to achieve this. Have a look at PrimeFaces `<p:remoteCommand>` and OmniFaces `<o:commandScript>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `<h:inputHidden`

But you can use the following thing:

```
<h:inputText id="json" value="#{indexManaged.json}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.myListener}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

and trigger it with jquery like this:

```
$("#json").change();// instead of `json` you might be needed to provide 
  //full id like this,  $("#myform\\:json").change()
```

Comment: Event is firing... but I'm not being redirected to the new page.