# Disable/enable a JSF input component depending on value of another input component

Tags: jsf

I have two radio buttons:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.choice}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="yes" itemLabel="YES" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="no" itemLabel="NO" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

<p:calendar value="#{bean.date}" />
```

If the "no" button is selected, the text input field of the calendar should be disabled (greyed out). How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just let the target input component's `disabled` attribute check the value of the source input and use `<f:ajax>` in the source component to update the target component. It will cause the `disabled` attribute to be re-evaluated. No need for a value change listener nor an additional property.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.choice}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="yes" itemLabel="YES" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="no" itemLabel="NO" />
    <f:ajax render="calendar" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

<p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{bean.date}" disabled="#{bean.choice eq 'no'}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)
- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason. I still can choose the date on the calendar. I want the field of the calendar be grayed out or non-clickable or something.

Comment: Works for me. Answer is complete and as-is (provided that it's already inside a `<h:form>`). Apparently you modified it too much in such way that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Excellent as always BalusC !

Answer (score 2):

You can have method in your `myBean` which is a valueChangeListener event.

```
   private boolean caldisabled;  // with getter and setter

   public void checkSelectedVal(ValueChangeEvent event){

      String selectedVal=event.getNewValue().toString();
      if("NO".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedVal)){
         caldisabled=true;
      } else if("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedVal)){
        caldisabled=false;
      }
}
```

And in your view in `primefaces calendar` component set `disabled` attribute

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.yesNo}" valueChangeListener="#{mybean.checkSelectedVal}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="yes" itemLabel="YES" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="no" itemLabel="NO" />
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="mycal"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>

<p:calendar id="mycal" value="#{myBean.date}" disabled="#{myBean.caldisabled}"/>
```

And there should be another way to do this. I think as this `calendar` component is `Jquery datepicker` you should be able to do it using scripting alone with no need to go to bean and make ajax call

Answer (score 0):

For me this last solution works fine, but I had to change the event from event="click" to event="change".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).