# Why my JSF valueChangeListener for selectOneMenu doesn't executed?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I have created this valueChangeListener for a selectOneMenu in JSF:

```
<a4j:region>
   <a4j:repeat>
       <label class="select">
         <h:selectOneMenu id="onlyThis" value="#{bean.prio}"
            valueChangeListener="#{bean.prioChangeListener}" >
              <f:selectItems value="#{bean.prioSelectItems}" />
          </h:selectOneMenu> 
       </label>
    </a4j:repeat>
 </a4j:region>
```

I don´t understand the reason, why this valueChangeListener won´t be executed, if an another value was select in ths xhtml page.

Is there a mistake in my code? The Beans are declared in the right way

Answer (score 5):

It's only executed when the form is **submitted**, not when you change the value:

So, either add a submit button and press it (you can also use `<a4j:commandXxx>` ones if necessary):

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" />
```

Or throw in some ajax magic to automatically submit the form on change. As you're apparently on RichFaces 3.x, use `<a4j:support>`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    <a4j:support event="onchange" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/)