# onchange="submit()" reloads my PrimeFaces Mobile page

Tags: jsf, mobile, primefaces, submit, onchange

I am having a problem with my JSF project, where I am using PrimeFaces Mobile. This page has several `pm:views`
I have a list of radio buttons, which looks like this:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.currentElement}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                                          onchange="submit()" 
                                          valueChangeListener="#{bean.elementChanged}">

                            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.currentItem.elements}" var="element"
                                           itemLabel="#{element.elementName}" itemValue="#{element}" />

                        </p:selectOneRadio>
```

My valueChangeListener looks like this:

```
public void elementChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    currentElement = (Element) e.getNewValue();

    System.out.println(getCurrentElement().getElementName());
}
```

The problem is, whenever I click on a radio button element, my page completely reloads to the start view, which has to do with the `onchange="submit()"`. I have also tried `f:ajax` elements, but this doesn't seems to be working with my radio buttons, because I can't click them when I use this.
Is there a possiblty to just submit my current form or pm:view (without the f:ajax)?

PS: I have also tried exactly this on a single PrimeFaces Mobile page, which completely worked, since the application just consisted of one page.

Answer (score 2):

When using PrimeFaces components, you should be using `<p:ajax>` instead of `<f:ajax>`. Just get rid of the `onchange="submit()"`. This indeed invokes a synchronous (non-ajax) form submit which totally explains the page reload. You also need to replace `valueChangeListener` by `<p:ajax listener>`. The `valueChangeListener` is the wrong tool for the job whereby you're merely interested in invoking a JSF action method when the newly selected value is being set.

All in all, the rewrite should look like this:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.currentElement}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.currentItem.elements}" var="element"
        itemLabel="#{element.elementName}" itemValue="#{element}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.elementChanged}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Don't forget to remove the `ValueChangeEvent` argument from the `elementChanged()` method. In order to access the selected value, just access the `currentElement` property directly.

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/11883021#11883021)