# Primefaces datatable cellEdit mode not getting modified new value

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf-2, primefaces

I've a data table with editMode="cell".
My problem is when I edit a cell (in either one of the editable columns), submit it, go to the listener method, and try to obtain the modified value using:

```
event.getNewValue()
```

It's not reflecting the edited value. It actually always returns the old value.
Consequently the bean doesn't get updated.
Any clues of what I'm doing wrong?
I'm using JavaServer Faces 2.2, Primefaces 5.0 and Spring Framework 4.0.3.

Thanks for any help.

Here's the XHTML code:

```
<p:dataTable id="nieoTable" var="nieo" value="#{nieoController.nieos}"
    editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellNieo"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{nieoController.selectedNieo}"
    rowKey="#{nieo.nieoNumber}" tableStyle="width:auto">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":nieoForm:wasIsGrid :nieoForm:paperModsumGrid :nieoForm:effectivityGrid" />
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{nieoController.onEditNieo}" update=":nieoForm:nieoTable :nieoForm:growl" />

    <p:column headerText="Nieo Number">
        <h:outputText value="#{nieo.nieoNumber}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="PLM Action Number">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="plmActionNumberOutput" value="#{nieo.plmActionNumber}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:inputText id="plmActionNumberInput" value="#{nieo.plmActionNumber}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="SAP Change Master">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="sapChangeMasterOutput" value="#{nieo.sapChangeMaster}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:inputText id="sapChangeMasterInput" value="#{nieo.sapChangeMaster}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Command">
        <p:commandButton title="Remove NIEO" icon="ui-icon-trash"
            actionListener="#{nieoController.deleteNieo(nieo)}"
            update=":nieoForm:nieoTable :nieoForm:growl" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here's the code for the managed bean (controller):

```
public class NieoController {

    @Autowired
    private NIEOService nieoService;

    public void onEditNieo(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            NIEO nieo = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{nieo}", NIEO.class);
            nieoService.updateNieo(nieo);

            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Nieo updated", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but I don't think you can access both old and new value with a p:ajax listener. But you can access the new value directly in the bean property. See BalusC's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener

Comment: Try adding these on your `p:ajax` for `cellEdit`: 
`process="@this" partialSubmit="true"`

Comment: You can also try to force the "getting the value" with `(String) ((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue()`;

Comment: @rion18 thanks for you comments, but neither of them work. Actually, the second throws a cast exception because the source of my p:ajax is in fact the dataTable which cannot be converted to a UIOutput. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar thanks for your comments. I've checked the answer you suggested, but I think it's not the same case. Or am I missing something? What I mean is, I may not have been clear, but my problem is that the new value is not getting to the listener. In fact, the value I get from `event.getNewValue()` is the same I get from `event.getOldValue()` and they are both the actual old value.

Comment: What class is your nieos object? (I'm asking because I tested on the same environment, and it does work, I'm trying to check every single detail)... Is it an implementation of `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem with my code.
In my managed bean I had the getter for the list of nieos, but not the actual list.
Of course it would never work like this. My list was never kept in the session.
So, I had this (without the actual list):

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NieoController {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private NIEOService nieoService;
    ...
    public List<NIEO> getNieos(){
        return nieoService.listNieos();
    }
    ...
```

Now I have this:

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NieoController {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private NIEOService nieoService;
    ...
    public List<NIEO> nieos;

    public List<NIEO> getNieos(){
        if (nieos == null)
            nieos = nieoService.listNieos();
        return this.nieos;
    }
    ...
```

Finally, I was forgetting to give my managed bean something to hold on to (if you get what I mean, ;) ). Now it works!
Thank you guys for all help. Sometimes we get stuck on the simplest things.

Comment: I was stucked at this too. Can you explain how it behaves? Why we must declare null there? Why the getter takes the data everytime?

Answer (score 0):

> I get from event.getNewValue() is the same I get from
>   event.getOldValue() and they are both the actual old value.

Me too. I missed the `<form>`. With it, it works!