# jsf - Get rid of "double click" in checkbox (PrimeFaces' selectManyCheckbox) to display values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

There's a checkbox inside a form that needs to be double-clicked for values to be passed to the bean. I suppose there's a double submit, but don't know how to get rid of it.

Code right now:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="displayBy" style="font-size: 12px" value="#{detailedDashboardMB.displayBy}" valueChangeListener="#{detailedDashboardMB.onDisplayByClick}" columns="6" layout="grid">
    <f:ajax render=":messages:growl detailed-chart" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Weekday" itemValue="Weekday" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Event method:

```
public void onDisplayByClick() {
    jsfUtils.messages("INFO", "Selected:", this.displayBy.toString());
}
```

First click (selecting the option) displays:

> Selected:
>   []

Second click (unselecting the option) displays:

> Selected:
>   [Weekday]

Comment: When you click the first time, html checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Yes. But the selected value is shown the second time I click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValueChangeListener doesn't work as you are expecting, it's a common mistake, maybe because it's name.

[Check this answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener) about the difference between `valueChangeListener` and `<f:ajax>`

> *[...] The valueChangeListener will only be invoked when the form is submitted and the submitted value is different from the initial value. [...]*

So... since the ValueChangeListener only works when the form is submitted, and that is not what you want to do, you can use `<p:ajax>` to update the components and call a method in your bean:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="displayBy" style="font-size: 12px" value="#{detailedDashboardMB.displayBy}" columns="6" layout="grid">
    <p:ajax update=":messages:growl detailed-chart" listener="#{detailedDashboardMB.onDisplayByClick()}" />
....
```

I'm not sure why your code take 2 clicks to work, but try to do with the `<p:ajax>` example.

Comment: <f:ajax> also have the listener event btw

Comment: It worked. I've used `p:ajax` before, but put an `event="click"`. Now I see it doesn't work that way.

Comment: In this case you should use `event="change"`, but it's the default p:ajax event for SelectManyCheckBox, so you don't have to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understood your problem. `valueChangeListener` is calling before the update model values, for this reason your `displayBy` seems not sinchronized.

Below the right code:

```
public void onDisplayByClick(ValueChangeEvent e) {
log.debug("OLD: " + e.getOldValue()); //is empty at first time
log.debug("NEW: " + e.getNewValue()); // is not anymore at first time
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Checkbox Selected", e.getNewValue().toString());

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```