# primefaces editor onchange is delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces editor in which the user inputs data, and another editor where some information must be outputted in real time as the input changes. However the the onchange event seems to always be one key stroke behind, meaning that if the user types "Hello world" the output would be "Hello worl". and if the user were to delete one letter (d) the output would become "Hello world". This is not the behaviour I want for my UI.
Both editors are inside a jsf composite component.

I trieed binding the input to an onkeyup event but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried using `valueChangeListener` instead of `onchange`?

Comment: @QueryLars: it serves a different purpose. You would still need some DOM event in order to get it to be fired without pressing the submit button. See also a.o http://stackoverflow.com/q/11879138

Comment: It must be client side.

Comment: How does user input go from one editor to another one's output exactly? Post some code.