# Update value of other input components on change of h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I have a JSF 2.2 form that contains one `<h:selectOneMenu>`, inputs and 4 buttons to call CRUD methods. In order to achieve the binding, I used a `valueChangeListener` so that when I chose an `id` from the `<h:selectOneMenu>`, I call a method which updates the object linked to the inputs. The problem is that the inputs don't change their value.

The form

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{avocatBurController.numProf}"
                 valueChangeListener="#{avocatBurController.handelValueCahnge}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{avocatBurController.lstAvocatbureau}" var="avcBur"
                   itemValue="#{avcBur.avocat.numProf}" itemLabel="#{avcBur.avocat.nom}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText value="#{avocatBurController.avc.prenom}" />
<h:inputText value="#{avocatBurController.avc.nom}" />
...
```

ManagedBean

```
    public void handelValueCahnge(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        String numProf = (String) event.getNewValue();
        AvocatBurDao avcBurDao = new AvocatBurDao();
        avcBur = avcBurDao.getAvocatBur(numProf);
        avc = avcBur.getAvocat();
        System.out.println(avc.getNom());
    }
```

`avc.getNom()` contains a value but the inputs don't.

Answer (score 4):

The `valueChangeListener` is the wrong tool for the job of updating the values of other input components on change of the current input. There are ways, but they are based on hacks/tricks invented during the dark JSF 1.x era when ajax didn't exist.

As you're already on JSF 2.x, just use ajax right away.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{avocatBurController.numProf}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{avocatBurController.lstAvocatbureau}" var="avcBur"
                   itemValue="#{avcBur.avocat.numProf}" itemLabel="#{avcBur.avocat.nom}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{avocatBurController.handleValueChange}" render="@form" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

```
public void handleValueChange() {
    AvocatBurDao avcBurDao = new AvocatBurDao();
    avcBur = avcBurDao.getAvocatBur(numProf);
    avc = avcBur.getAvocat();
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/)