# Primefaces p:spinner valuechangelistener submittedvalue not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, dynamic, primefaces

Having spinners in each p:columnS of my dataTable i saw that
the valueChangeListener methode is simply never called....so i tried the f:ajax listener, which is called but can't provide me with the selected value....it's madness!! I also read this great page : [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/) but still i can't get it working..

I guess that the construction within a p:columnS is a bit more complex, for example : it's difficult to give a dynamic ID to each selectOneMenu (even with rowIndex from dataTable and colIndex from p:columns component) SO has someone ever resolved that ???

Comment: Please provide some code that we can help you with. Also try to focus on one problem in each topic.

Comment: Finally, i made it! I overrided the embedded pf jquery.ui (1.10.3) with the jquery.ui 1.10.4, i then replaced p:spinner by a simple input followed by a jquery("input").spinner() (that simple command failed in 1.10.3 with the message 'spinner is not a function'. Some hack needed to trigger the change event, i'll post some code soon :). CHeers

Comment: to readers : i'm forced to use primefaces4 which comes along with jquery.UI 1.10.3

Comment: Here it is, <input id="updateQj_#{rowIndex}_#{colIndex}_#{rowQj.idQbt}" widgetVar="updateQjJs" class="editQj" 
              value="#{rowQj.listeDesQj[colIndex].quantiteRealisee}">                        
           </input>  
           <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery("input[id=updateQj_#{rowQj.listeDesQj[colIndex].id}]").spinner({
            min:0,
            max:#{rowQj.qMax},
            step:1,
            change:function(){             rmt_updateQj([parameters]);
            }
           });
           </script>

Comment: Now each ajax call is fully completed and tough not totally ok i managed to get a coherent system, thanks to jQuery

Comment: Note that the dynamic ID was not possible with a p:spinner : id="updateQj_#{rowIndex}_#{colIndex}_#{rowQj.idQbt}