# PrimeFaces switch with initial value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces inputSwitch:

```
<p:inputSwitch id="snoozeSwitch" value="#{dashBController.snooze}" valueChangeListener="#{dashBController.updateSnoozeStatus}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{dashBController.updateSnoozeStatus}" update="msgSnooze" />
</p:inputSwitch>
```

Now I want to give this switch an initial value from my DB. I get the value with:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        snooze = getSnoozeStatus();
    }
}
```

But I have trouble to update the old value with the new one.

```
public void updateSnoozeStatus() {
  if(snooze == true) {
    DBconnector.updateSnooze("true");
  } else {
    DBconnector.updateSnooze("false");
  }
}
```

**The problem:** My app always uses the inital value and so the switch is stucking on the state it has originally. Maybe @BalusC knows the answer :)

Comment: Where you defined this method: `updateSnoozeStatus` that is the one you are calling on the listener attribute

Comment: I am sorry. updateSnooze() actually is updateSnoozeStatus() - missed it in my transfer to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Tiny which work around could solve the problem?

Comment: Why that `valueChangeListener`? Get rid of it and reverify your question.

Comment: I removed the `valueChangeListener` - but it does not solve the problem. Can PrimeFaces inputSwitch handle objects of type **Boolean** instead of the primitive type **boolean**? (compare to answer below from @ForguesR

Comment: I had a similar problem that i resolved using immediate="true"

Comment: What is the scope of your bean ? What is the declaration of snooze ?
See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something your solution seems complex for something very simple.  Why don't you just use a getter and a setter?

The getter should load the value from the database and the setter should save it. I couldn't test the code below because I don't have PF 5.0.4 but it should be a good start.

```
public class DashBController {

  private Boolean snooze = null;

  public boolean isSnooze() {
    if (snooze == null) {
      snooze = getSnoozeStatus();
    }
    return snooze;
  }

  public void setSnooze(boolean snooze) {
    this.snooze = snooze;
    DBconnector.updateSnooze(this.snooze.toString());
  }

}
```

and simply :

```
<p:inputSwitch id="snoozeSwitch" value="#{dashBController.snooze}"/>
```

Comment: It seems that PrimeFaces can not handle Objects of type Boolean instead of the primitive data type boolean. Is that possible? Getting some errors I can not get rid of ...

Comment: Quite possible.  I edited my answer : now the getter and the setter use the primitive `boolean`. Can you give it a try?

Comment: If I use the primitive instead, I can not check if snooze == null. So I have changed it like: `public boolean isSnooze() {
    if (snooze == null) {
      snooze = getSnoozeStatus(); //return Boolean or Downcast
    }
    return snooze.booleanValue();
  }`

Comment: In my answer `snooze` is still a `Boolean` : I only changed the return type of the getter and the parameter type of the setter.

Comment: I've implemented and tested your suggestion. But if I toggle the switch, it does not run my setSnooze() method.