# ValueChangeListener is not getting called on inputDate JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, trinidad

I'm using MyFaces 2.1.17 & Trinidad 2.1.1. If I change the date using date picker component, then `valueChangeListener` is **NOT** getting called. If suppose I change the date manually (Instead of using date picker), valueChangeListener is getting called properly.Could someone please help me on this? Below is the sample code:

```
<tr:inputDate id="myDateId" autoSubmit="true" 
      valueChangeListener="#{myBackingBean.myVcl}" 
      value="#{myBackingBean.myDate}">
</tr:inputDate>
```

Note: Same functionality works fine with version 1.2.

Comment: Any in messages/logs? It won't be called on conversion/validation fail.

Comment: @BalusC No. It doesn't have validator. Also, no messages in the log

Comment: In case you want to use Ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener

Comment: @JasperdeVries ,BalusC Thanks for your help. Its looking like an Trinidad Jar issue. Its not working on IE 11 native mode but same is working in IE 11 compatibility mode

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed with the latest patch to Trinidad JAR. you have to use the new jar to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its looking like an Trinidad Jar issue. Its not working on IE 11 native mode but same is working fine with IE 11 compatibility mode.