# ValueChangeListener for a particular item in a Collection in a <a4j:repeat> tag

Tags: jsf, richfaces, valuechangelistener

How could I set fields of particular `Driver` in a `List<Driver>` by standart decision? without my own attribute:

```
<f:attribute name="hashCode" value="#{driver.hashCode()}"/>
```

Java BackBean:

```
public class BackBean {
    List<Driver> drivers;

    public List<Driver> getDrivers() {
        List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
        ...
        return drivers;
    }

    public void licenceReplacedCheckBoxChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        Boolean driverDocChanged = (Boolean) e.getNewValue();

        int hashCode = (Integer) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("hashCode");

        for (Driver buff : getDrivers()) {
            boolean findDriver = ( buff.hashCode() == hashCode );
            if (findDriver) {
                buff.setDocumentReplaced(driverDocChanged);
                buff.makeChangeDriver();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{backBean.drivers}" var="driver" rowKeyVar="rowDriver" id="drivers">
...
    <div class="controls one-control-group">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{driver.documentReplaced}"                 
            valueChangeListener="#{backBean.licenceReplacedCheckBoxChanged}">
            <f:attribute name="hashCode" value="#{driver.hashCode()}"/>
            <a4j:ajax execute="@this" render="..." />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </div>
...
</a4j:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the desired method in `<a4j:ajax listener>`.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{driver.documentReplaced}">                 
    <a4j:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{driver.makeChangeDriver}" render="..." />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)

---

Nonetheless, you could in your attempt just have passed the `#{driver}` itself instead of its hashcode.

```
<f:attribute name="driver" value="#{driver}" />
```

It's only an unnecessary detour.