# How transform OneSelectMenu of PrimeFaces to BootsFaces

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener, bootsfaces

PrimeFaces code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu onchange= " submit()" value = "${internacionalBean.locale}" valueChangeListener= "#{internacionalBean.cambiarIdioma}" id = "idiomaSelect" style="width:125px">
    <f:selectItems value= "#{internacionalBean.countries}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I changed `p` with `b`, but the `valueChangeListener` attribute is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

- Until we've implemented this feature we've obviously overlooked, you can use `onchange="ajax:internacionalBean.cambiarIdioma()" update="@form"`. Note the slightly different syntax: you have to put `ajax:` at the beginning to distinguish it from a JavaScript call, and you have to provide the parentheses.
- Like BalusC suggests below, you can also try to add an `<f:valueChangeListener />` facet.
- Would you mind to open a feature request on our bug tracker (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues)?

Comment: If the BootsFaces component also implements `EditableValueHolder`, then OP should technically still be able to nest a `<f:valueChangeListener>` (although I have a strong impression that just an ajax listener is already sufficient for the task OP had in mind, certainly if OP isn't at all interested in the old value). Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11879138