# Updating an UI value from javascript is not getting reflected in javabean

Tags: jsf

I am trying to update an UI text field in primefaces 6.2 using java script method. Though I am able to update the value from UI side, it is not reflecting in backing managed bean

Xhtml:

```
<h:inputHidden id="test" value="#{mybean.fieldname}" valueChangeListener="#            
{mybean.method}">
    <f:ajax/>
</h:inputHidden>
```

Javascript:

```
function update(){
    document.getElementByID('form:test').value="change";
    alert(document.getElementByID('form:test').value);
}
```

I expect my value changehandler to get called since I updated my value but nothing occurs.can some one pls tell where I am getting wrong

Edit :Actually I am trying to submit the value changed from UI side alone using Js to the actual bean value, basically dom alone is changed and kind of trying to submit the same using any ajax calls. but still it is not working. Refered this link:[When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener) Can some one pls give some insights on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Changing the value client-side does not make it submit the value... And there is nothing PrimeFaces in here...

Comment: And some basic searching like https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=jsf+change+value+from+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com results in many hits that might help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)

Comment: Hi , thanks all for the inputs. I actually tried out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener this. But that does not work though :(

Comment: There are lots of things in there, **what** did you try? What was the result? 'Did not work' is to vage and to little info to help with. [mcve] please!

Comment: I just added a f:ajax code as mentioned in Baluc's answer. as it has been specified that a change in the dom will be submitted automatically which is what i actually want. Just now updated the code. pls help

Comment: Please debug as a developer... is the value send to the server in an http request at all? Is the setter called? What if you add a listener to ajax? Is that called?

Comment: By the way.. this all smells like a XY problem. Shouldn't you just use a remoteCommand with parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kukeltje I tried debugging it by adding listener and also the setters are not at all called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JasperdeVries I am not aware of this. I will explore this and try. Thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger explicitly a change event by JavaScript if you set a value by JavaScript.

Comment: Care to explain how you would "explicitly trigger a change event"?

Comment: Thanks for the link @To

Comment: @Toru: That is what an `f:ajax` adds for you when used with the right event