# Autofill several h:inputText on h:selectOneMenu change

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have a h:selectOneMenu with information that comes from a TreeMap, whose information comes from a database. The TreeMap contains the primary keys and values of several users (first and last name, and an integer).

And bellow the h:selectOneMenu, I have a couple of h:inputText. Here is the code:

```
<h:form>
    <table border="1">
        <thead><tr><th colspan="99">User</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel value="ID:"/></td>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="usrid" value="#{webUser.id}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select One" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{webUser.availableUsers}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </td>
                <td><h:message for="usrid"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel value="First Name:"/></td>
                <td><h:inputText id="name" value="#{webUser.name}" required="true" maxlength="20"/></td>
                <td><h:message for="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel value="Last Name:"/></td>
                <td><h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{webUser.lastName}" required="true" maxlength="20"/></td>
                <td><h:message for="lastName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel value="Balance:"/></td>
                <td><h:inputText id="balance" value="#{webUser.balance}" required="true" onkeypress="if (event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"/></td>
                <td><h:message for="balance"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{webUser.edit()}"/>
</h:form>
```

The idea of what I need is to fill the inputTexts with the information of the item selected in the h:selectOneMenu. For example, if I choose ID(001), firstname(John), lastname(Doe), balance(100), I want to see the information of the person be displayed in each of its correspondent h:inputTexts, so that I can edit one or more of those values and press the Submit button, which does the whole update to database thing.

Here is the part of the .java that manages the editing and updating:

```
private UsersFacade uf;

private String id;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private int balance;

private TreeMap<String, String> availableUsers;

//...

public void edit() {
    try {
        Users newUser = new Users(id, name, lastName, balance);
        uf.Edit(newUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I go through this? Do I need to use some sort of ajax instruction within the h:selectOneMenu? Do I have to do some code on the layer beneath?

Or is there any way to see that if the inputTexts are blank, they just don't send new information to be updated, so the information that is already saved doesn't change to blank information?

Comment: The answer to all 3 real questions is: yes. The first question is too broad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with ajax:

```
<h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Test" itemValue="test" value="#{bean.test}" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Test2" itemValue="test2" value="#{bean.test2}" />
            ...

            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.change}" uptade="@form" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:inputText value="#{bean.test}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.test2}" />
        ...

    </h:form>
```

This works fine for me. You have to edited it to make it suitable for your application.

Comment: I would like to know what the ajax's value entails? In this example, what is the "change"?

Comment: the 'value' is the method which is executed in the bean so it is your 'edit method', the event specifies when to do it so 'change' means when the value of the 'h:selectOneMenu' is changed and you should know the uptade value. A link to the primefaces showcase for that [link](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml). 'Change' one of a lot values of the event. @frank

Comment: I made a mistake now it is correct @frank

Comment: i was just about to ask about that XD. Thanks a lot! It works exactly as I needed!

Comment: A valueChangeListener is something different than an ajax change event with a listener https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener