# Primefaces when required is true listener is not triggered

Tags: primefaces, listener, required

This is the short code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="field2" 
                ...
                 required="#{empty param[submit.field1]}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{test.onField2Change}" event="change" .../>
    ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Problem is that when field2 is null and field1 is null I receive an error because the required field is not selected and the listener is no longer triggered.

I want the listener to trigger, how can I do this, or what are my other options?
I already tried valueChangeListener and onchange instead but the problem is the same.

Comment: You could remove the required and check the value server-side, on form submit.

Comment: See BalusC's response to the question [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener). In this case you may need to write a custom validator method instead of using `required`.